# How to test if Facebook Ads attribution has been successfully integrated before launching our app?

Tags: android, facebook, google-advertising-id, attribution

Our team is currently facing confusion regarding the process of testing Facebook advertising attribution before releasing our app on Google Play. We have conducted online research and even consulted ChatGPT, but the responses we received were outdated.

Therefore, we are seeking assistance from someone who can provide us with a specific guideline on how to verify Facebook Ads attribution integration before publishing our app on Google Play. We've already integrated Facebook SDK for Android.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.